# magento 1.7 search not working as expected

Tags: php, magento, search, magento-1.7, e-commerce

I have change catalog->search_type to fulltext. But search not working as expected. For example my product name id Sony black camera and I search for Back Camera it dosenot show expected results for that.

Thanks,

Comment: How "Back Camera" will show result for "Sony black camera" it will not match eventually.

Answer (score 2):

Try to reindex catalog search results.
If this doesn't work check your catalogsearch.xml file. You must have this block in left/right column for catalogsearch_result_index page

```
<block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
```

For better search result I use this extension: http://extensions.activo.com/catalog-search-refinement.html

If nothing helps check out this link: http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Can-anyone-tell-me-why-2083430.S.125505665

Answer (score 0):

goto the admin  panel (System -> Index Management) and select all the

Indexes > Pick action is “Reindex data” > and the press “submit” button.

The search will start working.

If not then use the following process :-

Go to Path app/code/core/mage/catalogsearch/block/result.php
step 1 ) Uncomment lines 149 and 150

$this->getListBlock()
->setCollection($this->_getProductCollection());

Modify the line 172

change this line
$this->_productCollection = $this->getListBlock()->getLoadedProductCollection();

to

$this->_productCollection = Mage::getSingleton(‘catalogsearch/layer’)->getProductCollection();

when you will fix your code, goto the admin  panel (System -> Index Management) and select all the

Indexes > Pick action is “Reindex data” > and the press “submit” button.

Search will surely start working.

Comment: Its not working for me, any idea why.
My product name is "Elite: 16-27", it is searching for all products with Elite

Answer (score 0):

[Search Autocomplete + Search Suggest](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/search-autocomplete-search-suggest.html)

This extension is more helpfull for this issue.
if you time any character or word to define any where display on lis

[Front demo](http://demo.searchanise.com/magento/)

[image]